# Скачивание картинок по URL ссылкам в TXT-файле

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Есть TXT-файл с ссылками на сайты с изображениями, каждая начинается с новой строки. Как лучше по ним пройтись, чтобы подставить каждую из них В urllib, дабы сохранить картинки на ПК.

Пример TXT-файла:

```
//a/b/img.jpg
//a/b/img1.jpg
....
```

Сюда буду подставлять ссылку.

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, "img"+str(i)+".jpg")
```

Comment: Не совсем понял какая часть ссылки вам нужна для формирования запроса. С этой строчки `//a/b/img1.jpg` нужно только `img1.jpg`? или же только `1`?

Comment: img1.jpg. Но мне уже ответили. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы взять информацию, которая находится в Вашем .txt-файле, существует команда, которая идёт из коробки, [`open()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_open.asp).

В Вашем случае это должно выглядеть примерно так:

```
file = open("yourfile.txt", "r")
for line in file:
    # line - это одна строка из текстового документа
    # т.е. ссылка на Ваше изображение. Можете сделать print(line) для проверки
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, "img"+str(line)+".jpg")
```

Comment: Отлично! Большое спасибо.

Comment: Не за что. Если ответ Вам понравился, отметьте, пожалуйста, моё решение как правильное :)